How to inject something at the end of every render in Django?
I want to inject a specific HTML comment at the end of every render of HTML in Django. I don't want to write that at the end of base.html template, but want it to be injected by code. Is there a way for me to do it?

Yes, a middleware. My django-cavalry library does something like that (as does e.g. Django Debug Toolbar), but the gist of it is:
def inject_content(response):
    # TODO: check that the response is HTML content-type
    try:
        body_closing_index = (
            response.content.rindex(b"</body>")
        )
    except ValueError:
        return  # Can't find `</body>`, do nothing
    html = "<!-- Secret comment! -->"
    response.content = (
        response.content[:body_closing_index]
        + html.encode("utf-8")
        + response.content[body_closing_index:]
    )

    if "content-length" in response:
        response["content-length"] = len(
            response.content
        )


def my_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        if isinstance(
            response, SimpleTemplateResponse
        ):
            response.render()
        inject_content(response)
        return response

    return middleware

and then install my_middleware in MIDDLEWARE in your settings, as described in the docs.

I wrote a middleware class, added it to settings.MIDDLEWARE. When I receive response from self.get_response(request) in its __call__ method, it is of type django.http.response.HttpResponse and not django.template.response.SimpleTemplateResponse. In my view, I use django.shortcuts.render(request, template, context). What do I do now?

It should work just fine – the SimpleTemplateResponse check is just there to ensure the content has been rendered before the middleware attempts to touch it. I'd suggest adding some debugging print(response.content)s to inject_content, for instance, to see that you're actually getting there, etc.

Almost got it to work, except for these: 'Content-Length', should I pick it from response.headers or response? Also response.headers keys are supposed to be case-insensitive, so is checking for 'Content-Length' and 'Content-Type' okay? Writing a case-insensitive search on the keys, and then replacing the exactly key will be cumbersome. I mean, Django itself is littered with 'Content-Type', 'Content-type' and 'content-type'.

It's case insensitive. You'll need to update it in the response headers if you updated the content.
